# PostGIS - improving sql statement

Tags: postgis, sql

I've managed to create the below statement that creates a table based on a point in polygon query. However it creates a column that gives a true/false value which I then delete out all the f values from. Is there a better way of producing this statement?

```
CREATE TABLE crime_test AS 
SELECT a.*, b.town, ST_within(a.the_geom, b.the_geom) "within"
FROM crime_data a, nh_areas b;
DELETE FROM crime_test WHERE within = 'f'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think you need a `WHERE` clause:

```
CREATE TABLE crime_test AS 
SELECT a.*, b.town
FROM crime_data a, nh_areas b
WHERE ST_Within(a.the_geom, b.the_geom);
```

Comment: Excellent, that worked a treat.

Comment: Does ST_Within() takes into account postgis' spatial indexes?

Comment: Yes: http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Within.html